# Issue when running appium-doctor on cmd

Tags: appium, appium-android, failed-installation, appium-desktop

I am new to Appium. I am facing issues while installing and running appium-doctor on cmd.

I followed below steps for installation -

1. download and installed NodeJS
2. installed appium using cmd. version Appium-windows-1.20.2 from GIT
3. installed appium-doctor using cmd.

i see that npm and appium are installed property (Using npm -v and npm -appium i am getting their versions).

But when I try running appium-doctor -v
I am seeing message - LIBERTY LIBERTY LIBERTY and cmd keeps on running showing weird values.

Can someone tell me what has gone wrong here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaQxZ.png)

Comment: I am seeing the same issue here! Running Appium Doctor on macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Comment: @SteevJobbs Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I just reinstalled appium doctor using the command 'npm install appium-doctor -g' and the program appears to be working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling Appium Doctor using the command:

`npm install appium-doctor -g`